# Importing Excel Data with Dates and Values and Plotting Time Series in Matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime, time-series, import-from-excel

I would like to plot a time series in Matlab of a data set I have in Excel.

The Excel file looks as follows:

```
Data:       |  Value:

2005-04-01  |  5.20

2006-12-02  |  3.12

...
```

How could I load this into Matlab and plot the time series of it?

Comment: Hint: have a look at [`xlsread`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) and [`plot`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).

Comment: @am304 Yes... but of course I did so already :-) I then get the dates as string, which I don't want...

Comment: Then you should tell us in your question what you've tried, with your code, and where you got stuck, with any error message. Right now, your question is too vague and suggests you haven't tried anything.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear, despite not having tried anything yet.

Comment: @p_thomson Can you verify if [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29802169/802378) is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 easy way of plotting dates, but I'll give you the script to read from the xls file first.

```
% Read from Excel
[N,T] = xlsread( filepath );
```

You then need to extract/convert the dates as follows. Dates are the 1st column of the text.

```
d = datetime( T(:,1) );
```

Then you can plot the variables as follows

```
figure;
plot( d, N(:,1) );
```

A sample plot is here

[image: Date Plot]

Alternatively, you can use `datenum` instead of `datetime` if you want the date as an integer instead of a `datetime` object using the following line.

```
d = datenum( T(:,1) );
```

Answer (score 0):

use xlsread to load in data as string, now converting the date and values can be done in a number of ways, the most strait forward way for your dates is perhaps using the str2num which allows you to read in the N th character as a number, for example:

```
string = "2005-04-01|5.20"
year = str2num(string(1:4))
month = str2num(string(6:7)) //%where the number is the N th character in string, and has to be numerical or the str2num will return error

//%Note that this method does not read non-numerical strings, in your case "-" "|" will not be read.
```

I believe this is one of the faster methods, since it mainly involve a type conversion on a standard format of data. Any other suggestions?

PS: in your time series plot, I would suggest converting your dates into a long number, i.e. 20050401, 20061202, etc; which would be most efficient. (you can do this by years*1000+months*100+days.

Comment: While this solution will help parse/extract the year and month, I don't think this is what the OP wanted

Comment: Also the long number isn't a linear scaling, which is what you usually want

Comment: My `datenum` method would work better, but that's already included in my solution